# Efficient way to count/sum rows in dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm working with a large flight delay dataset trying to predict the flight delay based on multiple new features. Based on a plane's tailnumber, I want to count the number of flights and sum the total airtime the plane has done in the past X (to be specified) hours/days to create a new "usage" variable.

Example of data (excluded airtime:

```
ID                     tail_num deptimestamp     dep_delay distance air_time
2018-11-13-1659_UA2379 N14118    13/11/2018 16:59       -3   2425    334
2018-11-09-180_UA275   N13138    09/11/2018 18:00       -3   2454    326
2018-06-04-1420_9E3289 N304PQ    04/06/2018 14:20       -2    866    119
2018-09-29-1355_WN3583 N8557Q    29/09/2018 13:55       -5    762    108
2018-05-03-815_DL2324  N817DN    03/05/2018 08:15        0   1069    138
2018-01-12-1850_NK347  N635NK    12/01/2018 18:50      100    563     95
2018-09-16-1340_OO4721 N242SY    16/09/2018 13:40       -3    335     61
2018-06-06-1458_DL2935 N351NB    06/06/2018 14:58        1    187     34
2018-06-25-1030_B61    N965JB    25/06/2018 10:30       48   1069    143
2018-12-06-1215_MQ3617 N812AE    06/12/2018 12:15       -9    427     76
```

Example output for give = 'all' (not based on example data):

```
2018-12-31-2240_B61443    (1, 152.0, 1076.0, 18.0)
```

I've written a function to be applied to each row that filters the dataframe for flights with the same tail number and within the specified time frame and then gives back either the number of flights/total airtime or a dataframe containing the flights in question. It works but take a long time (around 3 hours calculating for a subset of 400k flights but filtering the entire dataset of over 7m rows). Is there a way to speed this up?

```py
def flightsbefore(ID, 
                  give = 'number',
                  direction = 'before',
                  seconds = 0, 
                  minutes = 0, 
                  hours = 0, 
                  days = 0, 
                  weeks = 0, 
                  months = 0, 
                  years = 0):

    """ Takes the ID of a flight and a time unit to return the flights of that plane within that timeframe"""

    tail_num = dfallcities.loc[ID,'tail_num']
    date = dfallcities.loc[ID].deptimestamp

    #dfallcities1 = dfallcities[(dfallcities.a != -1) & (dfallcities.b != -1)]

    if direction == 'before':
        timeframe = dfallcities.loc[ID].deptimestamp - datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds, 
                                                        minutes = minutes, 
                                                        hours = hours, 
                                                        days = days, 
                                                        weeks = weeks)

        output = dfallcities[(dfallcities.tail_num == tail_num) & \
                    (dfallcities.deptimestamp >= timeframe) & \
                    (dfallcities.deptimestamp < date)]

    else:
        timeframe = dfallcities.loc[ID].deptimestamp + datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds, 
                                                        minutes = minutes, 
                                                        hours = hours, 
                                                        days = days, 
                                                        weeks = weeks)

        output = dfallcities[(dfallcities.tail_num == tail_num) & 
                             (dfallcities.depTimestamp <= timeframe) & 
                             (dfallcities.deptimestamp >= date)]

    if give == 'number':
        return output.shape[0]

    elif give == 'all':

        if output.empty:
            prev_delay = 0

        else: 
            prev_delay = np.max((output['dep_delay'].iloc[-1],0))


        return (output.shape[0], output['air_time'].sum(),output['distance'].sum(), prev_delay)

    elif give == 'flights':
        return output.sort_values('deptimestamp')
    else:
        raise ValueError("give must be one of [number, all, flights]")
```

No errors but simply very slow

Comment: this looks like a `grouby` and `rolling`. give a try to `df.set_index('deptimestamp').groupby('tail_num').rolling('Xs').agg({'air_time':['count','sum'],'distance':'sum'})`, where `X` is the number of seconds you want to look back to. But without enough data from a same tail number, it is difficult to be sure it will work

Comment: @Ben.T Thank you so much! Using your groupby and rolling suggestion to first create a "lookup table" for each plane and then simply applying a lookup in it to my dataframe using the tail number and timestamp decreased the running time from over 3 hours to a bit over 4 minutes! 

Highly appreciate it!

Comment: One more question: 
Is there a way to exclude the most recent observation in the rolling aggregation? (as I don't want to include the flight itself)

Comment: I guess the faster way would be to create columns with the methods above; let's say one is called `air_time_sum`, and then after you remove the value of air_time row_wise: do `df.air_time_sum -= df.air_time `. for count column just remove 1